# How to resolve Magento Admin Catalog Products Search Issue

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.3

I am using Magento 2.3.5 version and facing below issue in admin.

I have tried all the solution available on google so far. Also delete ui_bookmark entries, this solve issue for that time but again same issue generate.

Now is there any solution for this issue.

P.S. How to create a observer on search event for admin catalog products search so I can delete entries from UI_bookmark table for each time user click on search.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is because some products has empty SKU.
I found the solution from here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232021/magento2-error-something-went-wrong-with-processing-the-default-view-and-we-ha